# Advanced Installer- Preventing MSIX Installation from Overwriting Files in a Subfolder

Tags: windows-installer, advanced-installer, msix

I'm currently facing an issue while creating an MSIX file using **Advanced installer** v21.3.1. My objective is to ensure that during the installation process, the MSIX file doesn't overwrite files within a specific subfolder.

Here's what I've tried so far:
*I set the overwrite condition to "OLDPRODUCTS" for both files and the folder using the following configuration:
**Properties → Operations → Do not overwrite existing file; condition: OLDPRODUCTS.***

However, I've observed that while this method works perfectly for files located in the root directory of my application folder, it's not effective for files within a subfolder.

Is there a specific setting or condition that needs to be applied to prevent the MSIX installation from overwriting files within a subfolder?